# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing election port for server: 1

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to kafka and i started doing the Zookeeper cluster setup by refering https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-setup-zookeeper-cluster-for-kafka/

This has three zookeeper instance, I am able to start the fist zookeeper instance but in the second node zookeeper is not started.

I used this command to start zookeeper - `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

I also created myid file with number 2 written in it.

Throwing the below error,

```
[root@kafka2 kafka_2.12-2.2.2]# bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
[2020-09-06 07:25:27,761] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-09-06 07:25:27,773] INFO Resolved hostname: 0.0.0.0 to address: /0.0.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2020-09-06 07:25:27,773] INFO Resolved hostname: 172.16.10.45 to address: /172.16.10.45 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2020-09-06 07:25:27,775] INFO Resolved hostname: 172.16.10.44 to address: /172.16.10.44 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2020-09-06 07:25:27,776] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/zookeeper.properties
       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing election port for server: 1
       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:369)
       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:152)
       ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Comment: Please show your config file. Error seems to say your quorum addresses are missing ports

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers finally. Actually i missed to mention the port(2888) for `server.1` in `config/zookeeper.properties`.

Issue

```
server.1=<ip of first server>:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=<ip of third server>:2888:3888
```

Working

```
server.1=<ip of first server>:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=<ip of third server>:2888:3888
```